# Alembic migration issue with PostgreSQL schema and invalid one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

I've created a database and schema in Postgres. I have my models and when I run `python manager.py db migrate` which uses Flask-Migrate, I get the error below. However, the `db init` command works.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) no schema has been selected to create in
```

Now when I add `__tablename__` and `__table_args__ = {"schema": "name_of_schema"}` to my models, I get the error below for both, `db init` and `db migrate`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'deploy.instance_id' could not find table 'instance' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

My relationships however, look okay. I've seen many examples and they worked properly on SQLite without Flask-Migrate.

I have three tables as follows (removing most columns):

```
class Application(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'application'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"v1"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    instances = db.relationship('Instance', backref='application', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ID %r>' % (self.id)


class Instance(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'instance'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"v1"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    host = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    application_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('application.id'))
    deploys = db.relationship('Deploy', backref='instance', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ID %r>' % (self.id)


class Deploy(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'deploy'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"v1"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    instance_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('instance.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ID %r>' % (self.id)
```

The relationships are:

- Application to Instance (one-to-many; one application many instances)
- Instance to Deploy (one-to-many; one instance many deploys)

When I remove all relationships and create a standalone table, I still get the first error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) no schema has been selected to create in`.  What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgresql has the concept of a "default schema", which is set using SEARCH_PATH.  It sounds like the user you are connecting as does not have this configured.   Take a look at [Client Connection Defaults](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html) on the Postgresql website.

For the foreign key error, when you use an explicit `schema` argument with a `Table`, that name needs to be specified in `ForeignKey` objects as well:

```
ForeignKey('myschema.mytable.id')
```

Comment: That's what I was missing, not specifying the schema in the ForeignKey. Thank you!